# Is it possible to embed a page from an Aura Experience Cloud Site in an iframe on an external domain?

Tags: experience-cloud, iframe, clickjacking

I am trying to embed an Aura Experience Cloud Site page in an iframe on an external domain.

With reference to this documentation - https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=sf.networks_clickjack_protection.htm&type=5 - I have followed the steps in the '**Enable ClickJack Protection for Experience Builder Sites section**'.

In the Experience Builder, I have selected '**Allow framing of site or community pages on external domains (good protection)**' and then added a Trusted Domain. I have enabled public access to the Experience Cloud Site for none logged in guests and published and activated the Site. I have also added the Trusted Domain to the CSP Trusted Sites list.

When I attempt to embed the Experience Cloud Site page in an iframe on the trusted domain, the iframe is greyed out with a 'refused to connect' message and I get the following error message in the console -

'***Refused to frame '{my domain}' because an ancestor violates the following Content Security Policy directive: "frame-ancestors 'self' {external domain}".***'

While I recognise that this feature is not available for Enhanced LWR sites, the documentation seems to suggest that this should work for Aura Sites.

Has anyone managed to achieve this and if so, can you share your steps?

Many thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: I have successfully done this for aura digital experience pages in the last month. I set clickjack protection to selected domains, though I did not use public access. I don't think I had to set up CSP.